# menu items become larger when screen is rotated to landscape on ios devices

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I’ve been working on a bottom-fixed mobile menu for an academic website that displays at screen widths of < 600px.   It works fine on ios as a long as the device remains in portrait orientation.  However, if the screen is rotated to landscape and back while the menu is open, the size of the text and the height of the items doubles and some clipping occurs. The menu displays normally if closed and reopened. A live demo can be found here: https://creative.chbs.jmu.edu/projects/New-Mobile-Menu/
Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening?

I’ve been experimenting with using jQuery to force-close the menu on orientation change, without any success.

Comment: Please provide the minimal necessary code to reproduce the behaviour here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is being cause by jQuery or the css.  I've included all pieces on codepen: https://codepen.io/jennyoxford/pen/pmmgbW